# Read window.navigator.language in pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Is there a way to read window.navigator.language in Pug/Jade template (NodeJs/Express)?
I tried something like:

```
 -var lang = window.navigator.language
```

But is not working. 
Or more generally, Is it possible to read browser language within pug template?

Answer (score 0):

pug/Jade are html template language which is compiled and running on **Server Side**, they can only get variable values from **server side**, so it's not possible to read **client side** object likes **navigator**. You need to send expected value to sever side via  server interface, the other option is do some conditional rendering via pure JavaScript on client side.

Comment: I see. I ended up creating menu options in client, so that a URL requested to server points to change language. 
But is not 100% satisfatory yet as causes redirect error in Express, but at least I can read user intention and change language.